# Why am I getting invalid output in textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

The output of textbox 1 2 and 4 are coming as a single character followed with spaces.

Example: like the value in the DB is 40 then in textbox its appearing as 4.

The datatype is `Nchar(10)` and of one column is int. In both the case the invalid output occurs.

```
namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
        }      

        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(
                                 "Data Source=soniya-9393b956;Initial Catalog=tabby;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from students where ID=" + textBox1.Text, conn))
                using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                   while (rdr.Read())
                   {
                       TextBox1.Text = rdr["id"].ToString();
                       TextBox2.Text = rdr["name"].ToString();
                       TextBox3.Text = rdr["class"].ToString().Trim();
                       TextBox4.Text = rdr["roll"].ToString();
                       //  builder.Append(rdr[0]).Append(Environment.NewLine);
                   }        
              }        
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SomeMethod();
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Not enough details to know exactly, but may some of those fields you're fecthing from the DB be NULL?

Comment: FYI: look into parameterized queries to ward off SQL injection attacks and errors.

Comment: when i Select * from students; from SQL management studios

I get the proper values in the table.
But when i show them in a textbox. 

The values like 40 comes up as 4 in the textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adi, after looking at the source you sent and the database schema, it looks like it should all work, I'm wondering if your connection string is incorrect given the schema you sent in our SO chat session.  When I changed the connection string to my hostname and database name, it worked as expected:

"Data Source=**YourHostName**;Initial Catalog=**YourDatabaseName**;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"

You list *tabby* in your connection string, but in the schema you cut and paste in chat it stated `Use [Demo]` as the database, which leads me to believe it may be a connection string issue.

Comment: Ya, the database name was the problem , iTs fixed now,.... Thanks

But i was just wondering if the DB name was wrong at the 1st place then why could i get the values of some entries... Hmmm

Anyways thanks ! :D

Comment: @Adi: I'd say most likely, there was already a DB with that name from a sample project or something.  Otherwise it should have thrown if it couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Do your charsets match?  The unicode coming from the database stored as NCHAR might get mangled if the C# code is expecting something else.

Comment: Well if your using SQLserver 2008 according to this the charset used by NCHAR is UCS-2
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx

If its sqlserver 2005 it might be using a different encoding and could very well be UTF-16 so it might not be the problem. just something I would research

and I belive c# by default would be using UTF-16

Comment: you may want to read Jon Skeets article, I admit I haven't read it fully but I need to.  I bet it addresses this question.
http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/strings.html

Answer (score -1):

Could be that you just forgot to put your code in the proper brackets for SqlCommand and Reader:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * ... " + textBox1.Text, conn))
{
    using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
         ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you can stack using blocks, just like you don't need an { } on an if.  If you stack a using block, it contains the next using block as it's body.  using (x) { using (y) { using (z) { } } } is same as using(x) using (y) using (z) { }

Comment: My mistake, when I saw that brackets are missing, I didn't realise that there is only the While block below it. Although it is standard combination of SqlCommand and reader, I wouldn't use three levels of code blocks without brackets, bad for readability :)